# Book Layout with Fancy Footing Including Display of Text in Front of Offset Graphical Object

Tags: margins, books, layout, footer

I'm currently trying to massage the layout of my Master Thesis and I'm struggling with the arrangement of some specific graphical elements.

The desired layout includes a footer with a graphical box (coloured rectangle) behind a chapter title. The desired layout is visible in the image below.

---

[image: Layout of Thesis made in Adobe Illustrator]

---

What I have done so far is to use `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` to change the footing, and I've included the element but I still have trouble arranging them. I'm using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}` and navigating between odd and even pages. I have a wide margin facing the binding of the book and the graphical element and text should be placed in the margin space. This is why I use a large `\hspace*{13cm}` for theese. Idealy the text piece "CO-CREATION" or "CHAPTER 1" should be aligned with the page numbers. Whereas the coloured rectangle should be behind the text, aligned with the binding edge of the paper and slightly offset vertically (approximately covering half of the text from below).

At the moment I have achieved the layout shown on the image below.

---

[image: Layout this far page 1]

---

[image: Layout this far page 2]

---

Finally I have included my current script below. The Lorem ipsum filler text is shortent a bit in this version. I hope this isnt to extensive... I honestly dont fully understand the `\hbox` command that i use, but found that it was helpfull (trial and narrow) in other similar cases.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=8cm,right=1cm,top=1in,bottom=1in,marginparwidth=7cm,marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}

%%%%% Header and footer %%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line

\fancyhead[LE]{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont
\bfseries\itshape\footnotesize MASTER THESIS}

\fancyhead[RO]{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont
\bfseries\itshape\footnotesize A. BOB \& C. DANIEL}

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\fontfamily{cmss}\bfseries\itshape\thepage}

\fancyfoot[RE]{
\vspace*{-0.2cm}\fontfamily{cmss}\bfseries\itshape CO-CREATION
\hspace*{13cm}\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{Geometry.pdf}}

\fancyfoot[LO]{
\hspace*{-8.5cm}\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{Geometry.pdf}
\hspace*{0cm}\hbox{\fontfamily{cmss}\bfseries\itshape CHAPTER \thechapter}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse volutpat, tortor nec aliquet molestie, est orci consequat orci, in iaculis sem justo ac magna. Praesent mollis eget tellus in auctor. Nunc nec massa lacinia, mattis risus ac, ullamcorper elit. Suspendisse vestibulum scelerisque auctor. Integer et purus sed dolor dapibus posuere. In lacinia nunc vel dui sollicitudin lacinia. Nullam ac massa porta, suscipit mi ac, tincidunt sapien. Nullam efficitur venenatis orci et molestie.\newline

\newpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse volutpat, tortor nec aliquet molestie, est orci consequat orci, in iaculis sem justo ac magna. Praesent mollis eget tellus in auctor. Nunc nec massa lacinia, mattis risus ac, ullamcorper elit. Suspendisse vestibulum scelerisque auctor. Integer et purus sed dolor dapibus posuere. In lacinia nunc vel dui sollicitudin lacinia. Nullam ac massa porta, suscipit mi ac, tincidunt sapien. Nullam efficitur venenatis orci et molestie.\newline

\end{document}
```

As you might have noticed on the image, the very wide margin is used for figures etc. and this I have already solved with `\usepackage{marginnote}`.

I have great belief in the graphical potential of Overleaf and I look forward to your response!

- Leo